# Wrapping CompletableFuture to Mono with DynamoDb

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

I know the java DynamoDB's SDK is considered async non blocking but my question is:

**Q.** Does the dynamo update still need to be  on another thread with operator *publishOn* to be safer in a reactive context?

`Mono.fromFuture(table.update()).publishOn();`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the AWS Java SDK v2, you don't need to worry about delegating to a thread pool. AWS SDK already makes sure that you don't block an important thread. See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html#advanced-operations) for details:

> The AWS SDK for Java 2.x uses Netty, an asynchronous event-driven
> network application framework, to handle I/O threads. The AWS SDK for
> Java 2.x creates an ExecutorService behind Netty, to complete the
> futures returned from the HTTP client request through to the Netty
> client. This abstraction reduces the risk of an application breaking
> the async process if developers choose to stop or sleep threads. By
> default, 50 Threads are generated for each asynchronous client, and
> managed in a queue within the ExecutorService.

Actually, it even use more threads than it would be desired in a truly reactive application. Fortunately, the [SDK also gives option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html#advanced-operations) to opt out of that behavior if needed.

One more thing that's good to be aware of is `CompletableFuture` is eager unlike reactive type `Mono`. For this reason it is better to use the lambda version of the `fromFuture` method:

```java
Mono.fromFuture(() -> table.update())
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, I am using the 2.x SDKs. so if I used publishOn() then I would not be using the above AWS thread pool and use the Netty bounded thread pool, is there any downsides to using bounded instead?

Comment: No, AWS would still switch to its own thread. Unless you setup AWS client as in the last example on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html#advanced-operations